# Usage of FileNameFilter and FileFilter

Tags: java, file, filefilter

I'm coding a simple program to list the files *.class* in a directory in recursive way.

Initially I coded this:

```
public class Parsing{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f=new  File(".\\");
        readRecursive(f);
    }

    private static void readRecursive(File f) {
        String[] files=f.list(  new FilterByteCode());
        if(null==files){
            files=new String[0];
        }
        for(String curr: files){
            File currFile=new File(curr);
            System.out.println(currFile.getName());
            readRecursive(currFile);
        }
    }
}//end parsing

class FilterByteCode implements FilenameFilter {


    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        if(name.endsWith(".class")){
            return acceptByteCode(dir);
        }else{
            return  (null!=dir && dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory());
        }

    }

        private boolean acceptByteCode(File dir) {
            boolean res= (null!=dir && dir.exists() && dir.isFile());
            return res;
        }

}//FilterByteCode
```

But this list only the directory and subdirectories, not the file!

I solved using the FileFilter:

```
private static void readRecursiveFile(File f) {
        File[] files=f.listFiles(new FilterByteCode2());
        if(null==files){
            files=new File[0];
        }
        for(File curr: files){
            System.out.println(curr.getName());
            readRecursiveFile(curr);
        }
    }

class FilterByteCode2 implements FileFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        if(null!=pathname && pathname.getName().endsWith(".class")){
            return  acceptByteCode(pathname);
        }else{
            return (null!=pathname && pathname.exists() && pathname.isDirectory());
        }
    }//accept

    private boolean acceptByteCode(File dir) {
        boolean res = (null != dir && dir.exists() && dir.isFile());
        return res;
    }

}//FilterByteCode2
```

and this work, listing the file *.class*.

I read the difference between the **FileFilter** and **FilenameFilter** but I don't found the cause of difference of behaviour.

Comment: what `".\\"` is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `dir` argument in [`FilenameFilter#accept()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html#accept%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) represents the parent directory the file was found in, not the file itself as you seem to expect. So among others `dir.isFile()` will always return `false` in your `FilenameFilter` approach which makes that `acceptByteCode()` will always return `false`.